# Specify a decimal value as exact

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, arbitrary-precision

I would like to specify that a number is exact, even though it contains a decimal point.

For example, I would like to be able to write some variation of `3.4` and have Mathematica interpret this as (exactly) `34/10`, not the closest floating-point value to 3.4.

Comment: Try `Rationalize` - http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html

Comment: Once you have rationalized 3.4 in 34/10, Mathematica will always automaticaly and systematically reduce it to 17/5. That's a problem for lisibility

Comment: You can also use `Round[3.4, 1/10]`

Comment: I don't care about the way the number is stored as a rational, just that it is an exact quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to my comment, the basic way is `Rationalize`, but if you want to have the denominator always be a power of 10 I wrote a snippet that uses the length of the real number to determine the power of 10:

```
fraction[num_] := With[
  (*Get the number of digits and the automatic rational*)
  {digits = RealDigits[num], r = Rationalize[num]},
  With[
    {
      (*Decide the power of 10 to be the denominator*)
      d = 10^(Replace[First[digits], {x___, 0 ...} :> Length[{x}]] -Last[digits])
    }, 
    (*If an integer is entered leave it alone*)
    If[
      d == 1,
      r,
      With[
        {n = Numerator[r]*d /Denominator[r]},
        (*HoldForm stops Mathematica from evaluating this any more*)
        HoldForm[n/d ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

It's a little complex but should be fairly robust.

Comment: You can use the undocumented ``Internal`RationalNoReduce[n, d]`` instead of `HoldForm[n/d]` so that it can still be treated as a number without having to keep invoking `ReleaseHold[]`.

Comment: I don't care about the denominator being a power of 10.

Comment: Given you explicitly stated exactly 34/10 in your question I thought it would be useful to have (also in response to andre's comment).  Either way, the simple solution is at the start - `Rationalize`.